# How to make expect's expect command fail if the output isn't matched?

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

Given the very simple script `script.expect`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn bash
expect "#"
send "/bin/false; echo \"process returned with $?\"\r"
expect -exact "process returned with 0"
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

I don't seem to be able how the script can not fail since `/bin/false` will cause the `echo` command to print `process returned with 1`, thus `process returned with 0` can never be matched on the `expect` command. I expect `expect script.expect` to fail with return code 1 after `expect -exact "process returned with 0"`.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn bash
expect "#"
send "/bin/true; echo \"process returned with $?\"\r"
expect -exact "process returned with 0" {
  send -- "exit\r"
  expect eof
  exit 0
}
exit 1
```

Even if I change the logic of my "application" in order to be able to test it with a positive/logically negated flow the outcome is still unexplainable.

I worked through

- [How to make expect command in expect program script to wait for exact string matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071636/how-to-make-expect-command-in-expect-program-script-to-wait-for-exact-string-mat)
- https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66520/error-handling-in-expect
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79310/expect-script-within-bash-exit-codes?rq=1

and have no clue why `expect` is behaving this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first script, the `expect -exact...` command is "succeeding" with a *timeout*. The default timeout is 10 seconds, and the default action on timeout is to do nothing. So the commands waits 10 seconds, matches timeout, and returns, so we continue with the next command.

You can explicitly match for timeout:

```
expect {
    -exact "process returned with 0" {}
    timeout { puts "timeout!"; exit 1 }
}
```

To avoid the wait to timeout, you can use a regexp that will match whether `$?` is 0 or 1 (or other numbers). If you put part of the regexp in a capture group `()`, you can then find it in built-in variable `$expect_out(1,string)`:

```
expect -re {process returned with ([0-9]+)}
set returncode $expect_out(1,string)
puts "we got $returncode"
exit $returncode
```

Note, the regexp uses `{}` style quotes, because `""` quotes dont allow you to use `[]` inside them.

Comment: I'd recommend you use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. You still put that in braces: in quotes you'd need to double the backslash.